# x86 Assembly output wrong?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm new to assembly language and I cannon figure out why exactly this is not working right. It is based off of

```
int main ( )  
{ 
    int a=2, b=1, c; 
    if (a < b)    
    {   
        c = a + 1;  
    }  
    else    
    {  
         c = a – b;   
    } 
}
```

And the assembly part looks like.

```
.model flat,c
.code

CalcResult_ proc
        push ebp
        mov ebp,esp

                                ;see if a<b

        mov eax,[ebp+8]         ;eax = a
        mov ecx,[ebp+12]        ;ecx = b
        cmp eax,ecx             

        jg   d                  ;Makes program jump dow to d if a < b
        add eax, 1              ;eax = a + 1

        d:
        sub eax, ecx            ;eax = a - b

        pop ebp
        ret
CalcResult_ endp
        end
```

It works fine when it jumps down to d, but when it doesn't it just gives me the answer of 0 instead of 1.

Comment: Because the code falls through into `d` after the `add`. You need another label at the `pop ebp` and jump there. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Also, nit: greater is not the complement of less, greater or equal is.

Comment: @Jester Thank you, that was a lot easier than I thought it was going to be to fix.

Comment: You could optimize by implementing it as `c = a - ( a<b ? -1 : b )`, so you only need a `mov` and then a conditional branch over another `mov` to create a source operand for `sub`.  So implement it like `if(a<b)b=-1;  c = a-b;`  Or you could use `cmov`.  And BTW, your C version doesn't take args; it would make more sense to write a C function that would compile to what you're trying to write in asm.

Comment: Btw you can use https://godbolt.org to inspect the assembly code generated for your C version.

Answer (score 0):

Also in my opinion the `JG` instruction should be replaced with `JGE`, so that if A < B does not perform the jump, otherwise it does.
Furthermore, after using the `Add EAX, 1` instruction, which is better to replace with `Inc EAX`, an unconditional jump must be followed, which goes immediately after the `Sub EAX, ECX` instruction:

```
.model flat,c
.code

CalcResult_ proc

        push ebp

        mov  ebp,esp

                                ;see if a<b

        mov  eax,[ebp+8]        ;eax = a
        mov  ecx,[ebp+12]       ;ecx = b
        cmp  eax,ecx

        jge  d                  ;Makes program jump down to d if a >= b

        inc  eax                ;eax = a + 1
        jmp  e

        d:
        sub  eax, ecx           ;eax = a - b

        e:

        pop  ebp

        ret

CalcResult_ endp
        end
```

in fact using the CMovL instruction the code is simpler
(one less instruction):

```
.model flat,c
.code

CalcResult_ proc

        push ebp

        mov  ebp,esp

                                ;see if a<b

        mov  eax,[ebp+8]        ;eax = a
        mov  ecx,[ebp+12]       ;ecx = b

        mov  edx,-1             ;edx = -1

        cmp  eax,ecx            ;compare A to B

      cmovl  ecx,edx            ;if A < B set B to -1

        sub  eax,ecx            ;A = A - B

        pop  ebp

        ret

CalcResult_ endp
        end
```